# Reusing Isomorphic / Universal React Components with JSPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, reactjs, dependency-management

I am trying to get an isomorphic / universal setup configured with a ExpressJs / ReactJs / JSPM stack.

The issue I have currently is that JSPM requires that I append JSX modules with the .jsx! suffix in order transpile them, so my component dependancies expected filenames are difference from the server template to the browser component.

Has anyone come across this issue and solved it?